# issue with section size

Tags: html, css, web

i have an issue with the section size its pretty small one 
would like to know how to make it right 
the section have one image on the left and text and info in the right
the image taken as 100% width but under it there are some space .

```css
/*Start About me */
.about-me{
 background-color: #555;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.about-me .image{
 float: left;
 width: 40%;
}
.about-me .image img{
 width: 100%;
}
.about-me .info{
 float: left;
 width: 60%;
}
.about-me .info h1,p{
 padding-left: 40px;
}
.about-me .hobis{
 overflow: hidden;
 margin: 40px;
}
.about-me .hobis > div{
 float: left;
 width: 50%;
}
/*End About me */
```

```html
<!-- Start About me section -->
 <div class="about-me">
  <div class="contaner">

   <div class="image">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300" alt="test">
   </div>
   
   <div class="info">

    <h1>about me </h1>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus quo aspernatur veniam obcaecati corporis earum iure error Libero <br>minima laboriosam asperiores ad obcaecati provident, exercitationem aperiam tempora ducimus excepturi!</p>

    <div class="hobis">
     <div>Web Design</div>
     <div>Socer</div>
     <div>Drawing</div>
     <div>Watching Movies</div>
    </div>
   </div>
  
  </div>
 </div>
 <!-- End About me section -->
```

[image]

Comment: Make the image `display:block`

Comment: what about 'height:100%;'?

Comment: @Stages percentage heights don't take effect unless the parent element has a height defined. In which this case the parent is not, so `height: 100%;` won't work.

Comment: @hungerstar thx for pointing that. didn't knew it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your image to `display: block;`. The space you are seeing is due to the space left for *descender* height. Inline elements, as an `<img>` is by default, provide space for the descender of lower-case letters like *y*, *j* and *g*. Setting it to block removes the descender height.

```css
.about-me .image img {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```